# Cannot send e-mail from queue process

Tags: php, yii2, queue, swiftmailer

I'm using Yii 2 with the yii2-queue package to send a batch of e-mails from a queue process.

```
class SendEmailReminder extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\queue\JobInterface
{
    public $userId;

    public function execute($queue)
    {
        $user = \app\models\User::find()
            ->select(['id', 'email', 'username'])
            ->where('id=:uid AND verified=false')
            ->params([':uid' => $this->userId])
            ->asArray()
            ->one();
        if ($user) {
            $body = 'test mail';
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['fromEmail'])
                    ->setTo('myemail@address')
                    ->setSubject('Reminder')
                    ->setTextBody($body)
                    ->send();
        }
    }
}
```

In another controller action I have this:

```
public function actionRemindUsersWithNoValidatedEmail()
{
        $users = User::find()
                ->select(['id'])
                ->where(['and', 'verified=false', '(NOW() - registered) > INTERVAL \'6 day\''])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
                Yii::$app->queue->push(new SendEmailReminder([
                'userId' => $user['id']
                ]));
        }
}
```

My web.php config:

```
'components' => [
..............
    'queue' => [
        'class' => \yii\queue\file\Queue::class,
        'path' => '@runtime/queues',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'host',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
        ]
    ],
]
```

and my console.php config:

```
'components' => [
    'queue' => [
        'class' => \yii\queue\file\Queue::class,
        'path' => '@runtime/queues',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'host',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
        ]
    ],
],
```

I call the action remind-users-with-no-validated-email and I can see @runtime/queues filling up with the queue files. If I execute `./yii queue/run`, I can see that the queue is emptied (thus, processed), but unfortunately no e-mail messages get sent. What am I missing here?

Comment: you have 'host'  for host  entry ... this is for not show your real host or is really this the value you assigned ??

Comment: To not show my real credentials and host details.

Comment: are you able to send an email with using `yii2-queue`? what does `->send()` return `true` or `false` ? you are not checking it anywhere, or try enabling logger for swiftmailer

Comment: That's the problem. I cannot seem to make the `send()` method work. It returns nothing. I tried to Yii::trace its return value, but nothing. How do I enable the logger for swiftmailer?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Because I run `./yii queue/run` from the command line, it has trouble to find the base url. So I had to insert this code in console.php (inside the component part):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'scriptUrl' => 'http://myurl'
]
```

I discovered the error after running `./yii queue/run -v` **with** the verbose flag. Thanks everyone!